# Make text auto scale to parent container

Tags: javascript

I hope I do a good job explaining this.

I am making a Tumblr theme, and am setting up the post titles in a way that text won't overflow unto a second line if it is to long. I want to make the text grow smaller as it reaches the edge of the parent  instead of dropping into a new line or getting cut off.

I tried fittext.js and bigtext.js, but I couldn't get either to work. And I do not think they would work for what I want, as fittext.js seems to be more responsive text, and bigtext.js always makes the text the same width as the parent  which wouldn't work with what I want.

Does anyone know I can accomplish this? I'm a noob when it comes to Javascript, so keep that in mind when responding. ;D

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to stop lines from breaking:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

Then, you need to allow scrolling:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Now you have access to `scrollWidth`. If it is bigger than `offsetWidth`, then the text is too big.

You can shrink the text one unit of font-size at a time (be it 0.1em, 1px, 1pt... whatever you want). Repeat this step until `scrollWidth` is less than or equal to `offsetWidth`. Ta-da!

Comment: `overflow:hidden` won't allow scrolling. Did you mean `overflow:auto`? Or am I wrong?

Comment: It won't allow scrolling by the user, but JS can scroll the element just fine. `overflow:auto` would add scrollbars, which in some browsers (read: everything except IE) screws things up.

Comment: Right, I guess I took "Then, you need to allow scrolling:" too literally. And I think the user can still scroll with `overflow:hidden` by highlighting text and dragging. Maybe I'm thinking of something else though. Haha yeah, I've dealt with wonderful scrolling problems related to this in IE :)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what offsetWidth or scrollWidth is or how to use them.

Comment: `offsetWidth` is the width by which the element offsets others. In other words, it's on-screen width (not exactly, but close enough for this). The `scrollWidth` is the width of the scrollable content within. They are both properties of the element you are trying to modify.

Comment: Would I be giving it in a [tag:javascript]-tagged question if it wasn't?